# Google Apps Script crashes when clicking on a link with stylus in Android 7.0.0

Tags: android, google-chrome, google-apps-script, samsung-galaxy

**Demo**

[Google Apps Script web application](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyZ4HIGg5Uq7sZJy0XODi4GQFohVui6dyiRRFgZZUIL9gP2dnBc/exec)

**Environment**

- [Samsung Galaxy Tab A](http://www.samsung.com/au/support/model/SM-P585YZKAXSA/)
- Google Apps Script web application
- Chrome 60.0.3112.116
- Android 7.0.0
- Device SM-P585Y Build/NRD90M

**Steps To Reproduce**

Click on the "Pen" menu icon with your stylus on the tablet model above and the app will crash (the Google Chrome "Aw, Snap!" message).

**Bug Description**

I thought this bug was related to jQuery UI autocomplete where if I used my finger to scroll up and down on the results, there was no problem, but as soon as I used the stylus on the results the app crashed.  I've since removed that library and the bug still exists. Additionally, I can now reproduce it by clicking on a menu link with the stylus.

**What I've Tried**

I replaced jQuery UI with another autocomplete and the bug was still there.

I built a new version of the app, hoping the crash issue would be resolved by coding lighter.  I used the UIkit ([getuikit.com](http://getuikit.com/)) CSS framework (which was not used before) and encountered the bug again - this time when clicking on a menu item.

The app does not crash if I use my finger - only if I use the stylus.

If I reproduce the code in a codepen ([full screen view](https://codepen.io/rarara/full/VMRVQP) | [editor view](https://codepen.io/rarara/pen/VMRVQP) ) the app does not crash when using the stylus to click on the menu item.

It therefore seems to be a combination of the stylus and the google apps script environment.

I have stripped the web application down to the `Code.gs` file which only contains the following:

```
function doGet() {
return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index').evaluate().setTitle("DUPLICATE FOR REPRODUCING BUGS");
}

function include(filename) {
return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
.getContent();
}
```

and:

- index.html (which contains very little HTML, see [codepen](https://codepen.io/rarara/pen/VMRVQP) or below)
- jQuery 3.2.1 minified
- UIKit js and css files

When I click on the menu link with the stylus, the app still crashes.

**Edit:**

As requested, `index.html` from the web app is below - but I think it might not be relevant as the bug has persisted across a complete rewrite of the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>DUPLICATE FOR REPRODUCING BUGS</title>
    <?!= include('css_custom_common'); ?>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="uk-flex uk-height-viewport mini_site_container">
        <div id="site_overlay" class="uk-overlay-primary uk-position-cover" style="
    z-index: 2; display: none; background: rgba(16, 30, 100, 0.8) !important;
"></div>
        <div class="uk-width-auto">
            <div class="uk-background-primary uk-height-1-1">
                <ul class="uk-iconnav uk-iconnav-vertical uk-margin-remove-top">
                    <li title="Test" uk-tooltip="pos: right" class="iconnav-item-color iconnav-item-hover-color uk-padding-remove-vertical">
                        <a data-content-name="test" class="uk-padding-small" href="#" uk-icon="icon: pencil; ratio: 1.3"></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="uk-width-expand">
            <div class="uk-background-default uk-height-1-1 my_right_content_area uk-inline uk-width-1-1">
                <img class="uk-logo uk-position-top-right" src="" alt="">
                <p class="page_heading"></p>
                <div class="my_dynamic_content uk-padding-small">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-beta.28/js/uikit.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-beta.28/js/uikit-icons.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What's the html look like?

Comment: Contents of `index.html` have been added to post and can also be seen in the Codepen.